How can I set colors on this indicator? SSL
I need some help. I can't adjust the color settings in my indicator the way I want.The only thing I want to do is make it gray during the crossover and change color after the crossover.
I am attaching photos of the current version (1), the version I want (2), and the code.
(1) My version:

(2) The version I want:

The code:
//@version=5  
 
// === SSL 60 === 
show_SSL = input.bool(true, 'Show SSL') 
SSL = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 60 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 60), math.round(math.sqrt(60))) 
SSLrangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 60) 
SSLhigh = SSL + SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 
SSLlow = SSL - SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 
 
// Trend and colors  
SSLcolor = close > SSLhigh ? color.new(color.aqua, 0) : close < SSLlow ? color.new(#ff0062, 0) : color.new(color.gray, 0) 
 
// Drawings 
plotSSL = plot(show_SSL ? SSL : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Baseline') 
plotSSLhigh = plot(show_SSL ? SSLhigh : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Highline') 
plotSSLlow = plot(show_SSL ? SSLlow : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Lowline') 
fill(plotSSLhigh, plotSSLlow, color=color.new(SSLcolor, 90)) 
 
// === SSL 120 === 
SSL_120 = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 120 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 120), math.round(math.sqrt(120))) 
SSL_120rangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 120) 
SSL_120high = SSL_120 + SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 
SSL_120low = SSL_120 - SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 
 
// Trend and colors  
SSL120color = close > SSL_120high ? color.new(color.aqua, 0) : close < SSL_120low ? color.new(#ff0062, 0) : color.new(color.gray, 0) 
 
// Drawings 
plotSSL120 = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120 : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Baseline (120)') 
plotSSL120high = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120high : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Highline (120)') 
plotSSL120low = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120low : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Lowline (120)') 
fill(plotSSL120high, plotSSL120low, color=color.new(SSL120color, 80))

I tried some var color codes on pinescript but it didn't fix my problem.

Compare SSLlow with SSL_120high, and SSLhigh with SSL_120low
something like that:
// === SSL 60 === 
show_SSL = input.bool(true, 'Show SSL') 
SSL = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 60 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 60), math.round(math.sqrt(60))) 
SSLrangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 60) 
SSLhigh = SSL + SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 
SSLlow = SSL - SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 

// === SSL 120 === 
SSL_120 = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 120 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 120), math.round(math.sqrt(120))) 
SSL_120rangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 120) 
SSL_120high = SSL_120 + SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 
SSL_120low = SSL_120 - SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 


// Trend and colors  
SSLcolor = SSLlow > SSL_120high ? color.new(color.aqua, 0) : SSLhigh < SSL_120low ? color.new(#ff0062, 0) : color.new(color.gray, 0) 
SSL120color = SSLcolor


// Drawings 
plotSSL = plot(show_SSL ? SSL : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Baseline') 
plotSSLhigh = plot(show_SSL ? SSLhigh : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Highline') 
plotSSLlow = plot(show_SSL ? SSLlow : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Lowline') 
fill(plotSSLhigh, plotSSLlow, color=color.new(SSLcolor, 90)) 

plotSSL120 = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120 : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Baseline (120)') 
plotSSL120high = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120high : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Highline (120)') 
plotSSL120low = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120low : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL Lowline (120)') 
fill(plotSSL120high, plotSSL120low, color=color.new(SSL120color, 80))



//@version=6
 indicator("SSL")
compareSSL(a,b) =>
    state = false
    if ta.cross(a,b)
        state := true  
    else if ta.cross(b,a)
        state := true
    state    

// === SSL 60 === 
show_SSL = input.bool(true, 'Show SSL') 
SSL = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 60 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 60), math.round(math.sqrt(60))) 
SSLrangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 60) 
SSLhigh = SSL + SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 
SSLlow = SSL - SSLrangeEMA * 0.2 
 
// === SSL 120 === 
SSL_120 = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(close, 120 / 2) - ta.wma(close, 120), math.round(math.sqrt(120))) 
SSL_120rangeEMA = ta.ema(ta.tr, 120) 
SSL_120high = SSL_120 + SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 
SSL_120low = SSL_120 - SSL_120rangeEMA * 0.2 

// Trend and colors  
SSL120color = close > SSL_120high ? color.new(color.aqua, 20) : close < SSL_120low ? color.new(#ff0062, 20) : color.gray 
 
// Trend and colors  
SSLcolor = close > SSLhigh ? color.new(color.teal, 0) : close < SSLlow ? #720f35 : #8b96be 
 
newcolor = #2013dd
if compareSSL(SSL,SSL_120) 
    SSL120color := newcolor
    SSLcolor := newcolor
else if compareSSL(SSLhigh,SSL_120high) 
    SSL120color := newcolor
    SSLcolor := newcolor
else if compareSSL(SSLlow,SSL_120low)
    SSL120color := newcolor
    SSLcolor := newcolor
// Drawings 1
plotSSL = plot(show_SSL ? SSL : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Baseline') 
plotSSLhigh = plot(show_SSL ? SSLhigh : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Highline') 
plotSSLlow = plot(show_SSL ? SSLlow : na, color=SSLcolor, linewidth=1, title='SSL Lowline') 
fill(plotSSLhigh, plotSSLlow, color=color.new(SSLcolor, 90)) 
 

// Drawings 2
plotSSL120 = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120 : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL120 Baseline') 
plotSSL120high = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120high : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL120 Highline') 
plotSSL120low = plot(show_SSL ? SSL_120low : na, color=color.new(SSL120color, 100), linewidth=1, title='SSL120 Lowline ') 
fill(plotSSL120high, plotSSL120low, color=color.new(SSL120color, 80))



This should give you an idea of what needs to be done feel free to tweak as needed. if you need help ping me.
